# What are some uncommon but valid portmanteau words that people use?

Tags: portmanteau-words

What are some uncommon but valid portmanteau words that people use?

Example: [Turducken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turducken) is a portmanteau of turkey, duck, and chicken or hen. People outside US are not familiar with this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a few that have entries in the Merriam-Webster Online dictionary:

- [advertorial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advertorial) (*advertisement* + *editorial*)
- [agitprop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agitprop) (*agitation* + *propaganda*) [originally from Russian]
- [alphanumeric](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alphanumeric) (*alphabetic* + *numeric*)
- [avionics](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avionics) (*aviation* + *electronics*)
- [beefalo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beefalo) (*beef* + *buffalo*)
- [biopic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biopic) (*biographical* + *motion picture*)
- [bit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bit) (*binary* + *digit*)
- [blaxploitation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blaxploitation) (*blacks* + *exploitation*)
- [Bollywood](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Bollywood) (*Bombay* + *Hollywood*)
- [brunch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brunch) (*breakfast* + *lunch*)
- [cablecast](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cablecast) (*cable* + *broadcast*)
- [carjack](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carjack) (*car* + *hijack*)
- [chortle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chortle) (*chuckle* + *snort*)
- [cineplex](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cineplex) (*cimena* + *complex*)
- [codec](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/codec) (*coder* + *decoder*)
- [digerati](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digerati) (*digital* + *literati*)
- [docudrama](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/docudrama) (*documentary* + *drama*)
- [dramedy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dramedy) (*drama* + *comedy*)
- [ebonics](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ebonics) (*ebony* + *phonics*)
- [edutainment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edutainment) (*education* + *entertainment*)
- [emoticon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emoticon) (*emotion* + *icon*)
- [fantabulous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fantabulous) (*fantastic* + *fabulous*)
- [franglais](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/franglais) (*français* + *anglais*) [french][french]
- [Frankenfood](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Frankenfood) (*Frankenstein* + *food*)
- [freeware](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freeware) (*free* + *software*)
- [frenemy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frenemy) (*friend* + *enemy*)
- [gaydar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gaydar) (*gay* + *radar*)
- [ginormous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ginormous) (*gigantic* + *enormous*)
- [guesstimate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guesstimate) (*guess* + *estimate*)
- [infomercial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infomercial) (*information* + *commercial*)
- [infotainment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infotainment) (*information* + *entertainment*)
- [liger](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liger) (*lion* + *tiger*)
- [malware](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malware) (*malicious* + *software*)
- [meld](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meld), meaning *merge* or *blend* (*melt* + *weld*)
- [mockumentary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mockumentary) (*mock* + *documentary*)
- [modem](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modem) (*modulator* + *demodulator*)
- [moped](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moped) (*motor* + *pedal*)
- [motel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motel) (*motor* + *hotel*)
- [napalm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/napalm) (*naphthene* + *palmitate*)
- [netizen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/netizen) (*net* + *citizen*)
- [newscast](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newscast) (*news* + *broadcast*)
- [pixel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pixel) (*picture* + *element*)
- [radome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/radome) (*radar* + *dome*)
- [redox](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redox) (*reduction* + *oxidation*)
- [shareware](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shareware) (*share* + *software*)
- [simulcast](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simulcast) (*simultaneous* + *broadcast*)
- [sitcom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sitcom) (*situation* + *comedy*)
- [skort](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skort) (*skirt* + *shorts*)
- [skyjack](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skyjack) (*sky* + *hijack*)
- [smog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smog) (*smoke* + *fog*)
- [soundscape](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soundscape) (*sound* + *landscape*)
- [Spanglish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Spanglish) (*Spanish* + *English*)
- [squiggle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squiggle) (*squirm* + *wriggle*)
- [stagflation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagflation) (*stagnation* + *inflation*)
- [sysop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sysop) (*system* + *operator*)
- [tangelo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangelo) (*tangerine* + *pomelo*)
- [televangelist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/televangelist) (*television* + *evangelist*)
- [thermistor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thermistor) (*thermal* + *resistor*)
- [tigon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tigon) (*tiger* + *lion*)
- [transceiver](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transceiver) (*transmitter* + *receiver*)
- [transponder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transponder) (*transmitter* + *responder*)
- [vlog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vlog) (*video* + *blog*)
- [voxel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voxel) (*volume* + *pixel*)
- [webisode](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/webisode) (*web* + *episode*)

Comment: I really hate some of these words.  Irrational, I know.  But the word "dramedy" makes me feel violent.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: you would have been a very sad panda in Soviet Russia, where every second word seemed to be "AgitProp", "ZamZavKhoz", "LenGosGorSelKhozSovet", "GlavMosVostMedPotrebMuzFabSredLechMashKultSoyuz", etc. (camel case mine, to highlight the structure). That stuff was everywhere, on the streets, on the radio, in schools, in books, in everyday speech. It completely got out of hand and degenerated into combining [these morphemes](http://bit.ly/aj7fMu) in any way people deemed necessary. (Yes, I *am* exaggerating, but still.)

Comment: @RegDwight: yes, that probably would have annoyed me.  The more the portmanteau word is a marketing/propaganda word the more I hate it.

Comment: @RegDwight: Note: I also hate portmanteau names for Hollywood couples.  Like "Bennifer".

Comment: Don't forget rockumentary, coined in 1969. And how about prequel and threepeat?

Comment: @cindi, not just a very uncommon spelling, but an out-and-out typographical error! (corrected, thanks)

Comment: Whenever I see "pixel" decomposed into "picture element", it makes me want to go around saying "pickle" instead.

Comment: @RegDwight - reminds me of an anecdote of the Russian/American experience: an American man and his Russian wife went to dinner with one of her classmates; they'd both majored in chemistry (been members of the "khimichisky fakultat"). After listening to their reminiscences for some time, he said "I hate to correct you, but in English we say 'fuck him', not 'him fuck'."

Comment: The OP asked for "uncommon" examples.  Televangelist, soundscape, napalm, alphanumeric, sysop, smog, pixel, sitcom, newscast... (and more if I took a closer look) are common examples.

Answer (score 4):

Lewis Carrol made this into an art form. One of my favorites from "Alice in Wonderland" was "Frumious" it is a combination of "Fuming" and "Furious"

Comment: Indeed, Lewis Carroll is the one who invented using the word *portmanteau* to describe such things. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau#Origin

Answer (score 1):

[Crocoduck](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Crocoduck&oldid=387804009)

> The crocoduck denotes an hybrid animal with the head a of crocodile
>   and the body of a duck, which became recurrent in debates involving
>   creationists and proponents of evolution, being used as a symbol
>   directed at those who do not understand the basic principles of
>   evolution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @tchrist. Well, since the link is to a specific revision of a Wikipedia page, it's probably pretty safe, but I suppose there's no harm being on the safe side, so I've added a definition.

Answer (score 1):

[spork](http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1167&bih=723&source=hp&q=define%3Aspork&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1167&bih=723&tbs=dfn:1&source=hp&q=Spork&aq=f&aqi=g3g-s1g3g-s1g1g-s1&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a7734adab34a689)

Answer (score 0):

**Webinar**: *web* + *seminar*.

Answer (score 0):

Staycation

Evacucation

Philanfatique (What your hosts get when your evacucation runs long)

Comment: Do you mean "philanfatigue"?  Do you have an example of this word, "g" or "q" in use?

Comment: I did ,   Yes.  I seem to recall hearing  it after Hurricanes Katrina and Rita n 2005  which was preceeded by the Tsunami in 2004.

Comment: The term is unknown to the google.  "Philanthropic fatigue" gets less than 300 hits; "donor fatigue" somewhat under 100K.  Not dispositive, of course.

Comment: I'm happy to know that it doesn't happen enough to rate  common usage.